# Layer notation for convolutional neural networks

Tags: convolutional-neural-network, notation

When reading about convolutional neural networks (CNNs), I often come across a special notation used in the community and in scientific papers, describing the architecture of the network in terms of layers. However, I was not able to find a paper or resource describing this notation in detail.
Could someone explain to me the details or point to where it is described or "standardized"?

Examples:

1. `input−100C3−MP2−200C2−MP2−300C2−MP2−400C2−MP2−500C2−output`
   ([source](https://arxiv.org/abs/1409.6070))
2. `input−(300nC2−300nC2−MP2)_5−C2−C1−output`
   ([source](https://arxiv.org/abs/1412.6071))

---

A good guess seems that *x*`C`*y* are convolution layers (*x* is number of filters? *y* is one side of square kernel?). `MP`*z* is max-pooling layer (pool size *z*×*z*?).

But instead of guessing, I would love to have a reference (which I could possibly also reference in a paper).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One paper referenced by the first paper you linked to is [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1202.2745). It explains in section 3 (experiments) the following notation:

> 2x48x48-100C5-MP2-100C5-MP2-100C4-MP2-300N-100N-6N represents a net
>   with:
>
> - 2 input images of size 48x48
> - a convolutional layer with 100 maps and 5x5 filters
> - a max-pooling layer over non-overlapping regions of size 2x2
> - a convolutional layer with 100 maps and 4x4 filters
> - a max-pooling layer over non overlapping regions of size 2x2
> - a fully connected layer with 300 hidden units,
> - a fully connected layer with 100 hidden units
> - a fully connected layer with 6 neurons (one per class)

From this, the answer to your question is:

- 100C3 means a convolutional layer with 100 maps and 3x3 filters
- MP2 means a max-pooling layer with non overlapping regions of size 2x2
- 200C2 means a convolutional layer with 200 maps and 2x2 filters
- etc with the "C" layers (means convolutional, preceding integer is the number of features maps; final integer is the filter size)

According to the second paper you linked, the subscript `_5` indicates five pairs of `300nC2−300nC2−MP2` connected layers ([see section 3](https://arxiv.org/abs/1412.6071)), and the `n` indicates "the number of filters in the nth convolutional layer is [300]n".  According to the accompanying model diagram (figure 3 in the linked paper), the `C2` and `C1` layers produce 1x1 output, meaning a scalar value. This would mean `C2` is a convolutional layer with 1 map and a 2x2 filter and `C1` is a convolutional layer with 1 map and 1x1 filter (though I don't fully understand what this adds).

Comment: Thanks, this is definitely helpful, especially the reference! There is one line missing from the original paper, proposed a change. Thanks again