# Common human-writable text format for specifying the architecture (untrained) of a neural network?

Tags: neural-network, tensorflow, pytorch

I am curious if there is a common *human-writable* text format for specifying the architecture (untrained) of a neural network.

There are informal notations such as [described here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/27248/layer-notation-for-convolutional-neural-networks).

I am aware of ONNX and NNEF, but these are for *fully-trained* models, and are not human-readable because they include all the parameters.

To explain my use-case more, which I believe is quite common-place for myself, and other researchers:

- You learn about a new neural network architecture, that you want to try training but with new data or with a different training regmine (because use a different platform or GPU setup).
- You google and find a github repo with the model defined in some Python file in your favorite framework---or a framework you don't understand. This is surrounded by a bunch of training and inference and preprocessing code that you can't use, and a pretrained model on a different data-set than you want.
- What you want is just to be able to grab the model architecture into a JSON, transpile it into your framework, and then insert it into your typically pipeline orchestration + training code.